# C++ error: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' string vs const char *

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++11, char

So, I am writing a simple, templated search function for deque container. Here's the code:

```
    template <typename T>
    void searchInDequeFor(std::deque<T> Deque, T searchValue)
    {
        for(const auto & element : Deque)
        {
            if(Deque.empty())
            {
                std::cout << "Deque is empty, nothing to search for..." << "\n";
            }
            else if(element==searchValue)
            {
                std::cout << searchValue << " matches " << element << ", an element in the deque" << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

And, here's how I am calling the function in main:

```
        deque<string> myDeque={"apple", "banana", "pear", "blueberry"};
        searchInDequeFor(myDeque,"pear");
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' vs. 'const char *')
```

Now, I've tested this function with integers, floats, doubles, etc., and it runs fine with those types, meaning my templating is working (for these types). This makes me wonder why I am getting this error when the function clearly knows that I am passing in a deque of type string and not of type const char *. Any help would be brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `std::string` and `const char*` (<- this is what `"pear"` decays to when calling the function) are two different types you both want to deduce `T` from, just as the compiler says.

To fix the issue, call the function with the correct type:

```
searchInDequeFor(myDeque,std::string("pear"));
```

Answer (score 12):

To fix your function to allow for implicit conversions, make sure `T` only gets deduced from the first argument, not from the second.

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template <typename T>
void searchInDequeFor(std::deque<T> Deque, typename identity<T>::type searchValue)
```

This way, when you pass in a `std::deque<std::string>` and a `const char *`, the compiler will only be able to use the first argument for figuring out which `T` to use. Only *after* `T` has been fixed as `std::string` can the type of the second parameter be resolved, as `std::string`, and this will allow for implicit conversions from `const char *`.

Comment: This is pretty sweet! Thanks!