# How to re-write templated function to handle type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

So, I have this search function for the map container:

```
    template <typename Key, typename T>
    void searchInMapByKey(std::map<Key,T> Map, T keyValue)
    {
        if(Map.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "Map is empty, nothing to search for..." << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            for(const auto & element : Map)
            {
                if(element.first==keyValue)
                {
                    std::cout << keyValue << "matches a key value " << " in the map" << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I seem to be running into deducing type issues, specifically this error:

```
candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' vs. 'int')
```

when I try to test it with the following code:

```
        map<int,string> myMap;
        myMap.emplace(1,string("a"));
        myMap.emplace(2,string("b"));
        myMap.emplace(3,string("c"));
        searchInMapByKey(myMap,1);
```

Because the compiler doesn't know which type to associate with the "T", integer or string.

Now, I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835980/c-error-deduced-conflicting-types-for-parameter-t-string-vs-const-char)  about the same type of error and was able to solve the issue by using C++ style strings. However, I don't want to keep handling conflicting type deduction errors on a case by case basis, and was wondering how I could write this function (using templates) to help the compiler better deduce which type should be associated with the "T" from the outset?

Comment: Whats is stopping you to use `std::map:find()` to search inside your map?

Comment: The second parameter should be `Key`, but `T`.

Comment: Then why can't you use `std::set` in place of `std::map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a mismatch between the type of the Map and the key types. 
But I would fix it not by correcting the order of the parameters `std::map` argument, but by changing the definition to be more generic.

```
template <typename MapType, typename KeyType>
void searchInMapByKey(const MapType & Map, KeyType key) {
    if(Map.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Map is empty, nothing to search for..." << "\n";
        return;
    }      

    for(const auto & element : Map) {
        if(element.first==keyValue) {
            std::cout << keyValue << "matches a key value " << " in the map" << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. You also just showed me a better way to write the rest of my code!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `mapped_type` of `map`, `T` for your key value, you should use `key_type`, so change the declaration of function to:

```
template <typename Key, typename T>
void searchInMapByKey(std::map<Key,T> Map, Key keyValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the compiler that the function `searchInMapByKey` has two parameters: a `map<Key, T>`, and a `T`.

For the call, you're passing `map<int, string>` and an `int`

From the first parameter, it deduces that `Key=int` and `T=string`.

From the second parameter, it deduces that `T=int`.

So it tells you that it has a conflict.

Comment: As @0x499602D2 suggested, I suspect that the parameter `keyvalue` should be of type `Key`.